# MultipleRequest in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I would like to know whether WSO2 Identity Server supports multipleRequests?

When I try to formulate the following request
:

```
    <Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" id="action1">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">GET</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" id="action2">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">GETT</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" id="subject1">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">cijoy</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" id="subject2">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">cijoyy</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" id="resource1">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/Entitlement_Sample_WebApp/protected.jsp</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" id="resource2">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/Entitlement_Sample_WebApp/protected.jspp</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<MultiRequests>
        <RequestReference>
            <AttributesReference ReferenceId="subject1"/>
            <!-- Is Subject necesary? -->
            <AttributesReference ReferenceId="action1"/>
            <!-- Is Action necessary -->
            <AttributesReference ReferenceId="resource1"/>
            <!-- This generates a normal single Resource request -->
        </RequestReference>
</MultiRequests>        
</Request>
```

It throws In determinant Error saying

```
 Invalid request  : Error parsing required ReferenceId in MultiRequestType
```

Any working sample? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with Balana XACML 3.0 . This [link](http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/08/16/resource-filtering-with-xacml/) would be of help.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.